# How to create a Word document header/footer in R Programming

Tags: r

In sas we have we proc report procedures.
In R we have RTF Package. I need to have in all pages of Footer and title.

Comment: it is not clear what you're asking. however, this may help you: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html

Comment: I have created the code In R similar to sas TL but the alignment problem, footnote and header is the problem for me. If the output is one page i am getting the output proper. If we have the output for 5 to 10 then the problem comes. Title and footnotes is are not there in the all pages. I need the footnotes and titles in all the pages of the output. Please can you send us code also if possible.
 

Thanks for the Help in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ReporteRs` package to create the Word document, and set up the template with whatever footer you would like.  You can insert one or more titles as headers.

Or, a simpler capability is in the `DescTools` package, its various Wrd functions.  Similarly, you can insert titles and use a Word template with the footers.

Comment: Note that the `reportRs` package is currently archived on CRAN.  It is no longer available.